# Python: increment dictionary keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a large (ordered) dictionary (between 10,000 and 50,000 entries):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict()
...
d[100] = [x100, y100]
d[101] = [x101, y101]
d[102] = [x102, y102]
...
```

I want to insert a new entry between the keys `100` and `101` in the dictionary and update every key which is larger than the first key.

```
...
d[100] = [x100, y100]
d[101] = [x_inserted, y_inserted] # new entry
d[102] = [x101, y101] # before d[101]
d[103] = [x102, y102] # before d[102]
...
```

How can I do this?

When I am deleting entries from the dictionary, I can use this approach

```
for key in d:
    if key > inserted_value:
        d[key - 1] = d[key]
        del d[key]
```

but this does not work when I am adding entries (because `d[key + 1]` exists before I update the key).

Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't seem very natural.

Comment: Why are you not just using a list!?

Comment: I am looking for a solution how to increment a subset of the keys of a dictionary.

Comment: `d = {}` is a regular `dict`, which *has no order*.  Did you mean an `OrderedDict`?  (Probably not.  Because that doesn't do what you want either.  "Order" in `OrderedDict` refers to insertion order.  You can't retroactively fiddle with the order.)  I'll second @ChadS.'s comment.  You want a `list`.

Comment: If you had some sort of order then why would you not just update the value? If 100 already exists updating the value is not going to change the key order

Comment: @maxie the point is you are using the wrong tool for the job. you shouldn't be using a dict in the first place. this is exactly the use case for lists, and not the use case for dicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do seems to be defeating the purpose of using a dictionary.

Anyway, if you're using an `OrderedDict`, you could take copy of dictionary keys first and then iterate them in reverse order, reassigning values so that a value formerly keyed by key `k_i` is now keyed by key `k_i+1`. When the boundary key value is reached, break the loop. Finally, insert the new value.

```
keys = list(d.keys())
keys.sort(reverse=True)
increased_k = keys[0] + 1  # use +1 to increment the largest key 
for k in keys:
    if k < new_key: break
    d[increased_k] = d[k]
    increased_k = k

d[new_key] = new_value  # insert the new item
```

This assumes `new_key` already exists in the dictionary, so the order is preserved.

Comment: Not mine but this could not possibly work as dicts are unordered, it would also not run at all using python3

Comment: @PadraicCunningham why wouldn't this work using Python 3? (honestly asking, not claiming that it would)

Comment: @thebjorn, you cannot index  a `KeysView` object.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Pretty sure the OP meant an `OrderedDict`. Changed the first line to use a list.

Comment: The first line should probably be `increased_k = max(d.keys()) + 1` since `keys()` isn't sorted..

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code that will actually work (and I believe it will work in Python 2 or 3).

```
def insert(d, key, value):
    # when you're moving up, start at the top
    up = max(d.keys()) + 1    # Py2: iterkeys() uses less memory
    while up > key:
        d[up] = d[up - 1]     # pull up each item
        up -= 1
    d[key] = value
```

Usage:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict((x, x) for x in range(10))
print(d)
insert(d, 5, "here")
print(d)
```

You can easily incorporate this into a subclass of `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class InsertableOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def insert(self, key, value):
        up = max(self.keys()) + 1    # Py2: iterkeys()
        while up > key:
            self[up] = self[up - 1]
            up -= 1
        self[key] = value
```

Note that an `OrderedDict` recalls the order in which items were *added* to the dictionary, and that order technically *isn't updated* by this process. (Order is kept internally by the `OrderedDict` class and we don't have easy access to it.) However, it still works because a new item is added, and that item, being the *most recently* added, appears as the last item of the OrderedDict—which just happens to be where we want it!

Still, `OrderedDict` isn't really what you want. And as others have noted, having this in a plain `dict` dictionary is not a great idea either. A `list` would be **much** better: more memory-efficient and much faster to insert.

Answer (score 0):

For insertion using the algorithmic approach you need to go to the last element of the dictionary and then shift each element to the right to create space for the element to be inserted.

Now, the issue is going to the last element of the dictionary, which is possible only if you convert dictionary to list.

```
d.keys()[-1]
```

It doesn't make sense to ask for the "last" key in a dictionary, because dictionary keys are unordered. You can get the list of keys and get the last one if you like, but that's not in any sense the "last key in a dictionary".

Since you have an ordered list dictionary seems to be a wrong choice you may think of using a list. Just in case if you have to bring in some solution convert the dict to list as mentioned.

Comment: `d.keys()[-1]` is not necessarily the highest key in the dictionary, since the keys do not come out in any particular order. `max()` should be used here.

Comment: @kindall yes you are correct, here the asumption is that the dic values are stored in order, which seems to be the case in the question